# How can make a dataset of elements of matrices in dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, matrix, dataset

I have dataset of 3 parameters `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'` in `.TXT` file and after I print them in 24x20 matrices I need to collect the 1st elements of `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'` put in long arrays in panda `dataframe` and then 2nd elements of each then 3rd and so on till 480th elements.

So my data is like this in text file:
my data is txt file is following:

```
id_set: 000
     A: -2.46882615679
     B: -2.26408246559
     C: -325.004619528
```

I already made a panda `dataframe` includes 3 columns of `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'` and `index` and defined functions to print 24x20 matric in right way. Simple example via 2x2 matrices:

```
1st cycle:  A = [1,2,    B = [4,5,     C = [8,9,
                 3,4]         6,7]          10,11]
2nd cycle:  A = [0,8,    B = [1,9,     C = [10,1,
                 2,5]         4,8]          2,7]
```

Reshape to this form:

```
          A(1,1),B(1,1),C(1,1),A(1,2),B(1,2),C(1,2),.....
Result=  [1,4,8,2,5,9,3,6,10,4,7,11] #1st cycle
         [0,1,10,8,9,1,2,4,2,5,8,7]  #2nd cycle
```

My scripts are following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

def normalize(value, min_value, max_value, min_norm, max_norm):
    new_value = ((max_norm - min_norm)*((value - min_value)/(max_value - min_value))) + min_norm
    return new_value

dft = pd.read_csv('D:\mc25.TXT', header=None)
id_set = dft[dft.index % 4 == 0].astype('int').values
A = dft[dft.index % 4 == 1].values
B = dft[dft.index % 4 == 2].values
C = dft[dft.index % 4 == 3].values
data = {'A': A[:,0], 'B': B[:,0], 'C': C[:,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B','C'], index = id_set[:,0])  

#next iteration create all plots, change the number of cycles
cycles = int(len(df)/480)
print(cycles)
for cycle in range(0,10):             
    count =  '{:04}'.format(cycle)
    j = cycle * 480
    for i in df:
        try:
            os.mkdir(i)
        except:
            pass

        min_val = df[i].min()
        min_nor = -1
        max_val = df[i].max()
        max_nor = 1

        ordered_data = mkdf(df.iloc[j:j+480][i])
        csv = print_df(ordered_data)
        #Print .csv files contains matrix of each parameters by name of cycles respectively
        csv.to_csv(f'{i}/{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None)            
        if 'C' in i:
            min_nor = -40
            max_nor = 150
            #Applying normalization for C between [-40,+150]
            new_value3 = normalize(df['C'].iloc[j:j+480], min_val, max_val, -40, 150)
            df3 = print_df(mkdf(new_value3))
            df3.to_csv(f'{i}/norm{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None)
        else:
            #Applying normalization for A,B between    [-1,+1]
            new_value1 = normalize(df['A'].iloc[j:j+480], min_val, max_val, -1, 1)
            new_value2 = normalize(df['B'].iloc[j:j+480], min_val, max_val, -1, 1)
            df1 = print_df(mkdf(new_value1))
            df2 = print_df(mkdf(new_value2))
            df1.to_csv(f'{i}/norm{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None) 
            df2.to_csv(f'{i}/norm{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None)
```

**Note2:**  I provided a dataset in text file for 3 cycles:
[Text dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oTf-2QDLo-n3UUTyY92h4zH8kffR0KAm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. You've also not asked a question and you've posed your workflow in Excel.

Comment: No dear just for transfer my idea I draw it

Comment: I can appreciate that and maybe others will follow better than me. I'm just saying that whatever that diagram was intended to convey does not work for me. I use Excel daily but I think this would be easier to understand if you kept the example just in Pandas

Comment: @roganjosh Due to respect to you I formulated in way you like, you may help me.

Comment: I have no clue what this asks for, but it looks like some reshaping, or stacking operation. In any case you may want to tag the question correctly with the tools you intent to use (pandas, numpy, excel?) and strongly reduce the complexity of the problem. I.e. shapes of 2,3,4 or so should be enough to clearly explain the problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i have data in text file for 3 parameter A, B, C  for some cycles and I mapped them into 24*20 matrices individually through cycles in order I want by using for-loop and saved them in csv files nicely now task is make a pandas dataframe  or reshape them to take each elements of Matrix A , Matrix B, Matrix C and put it together in for each cycle i.e. [A(1,1) , B(1,1) , C(1,1) , A(1,2) , B(1,2) , (C1,2),....,A(24,20) , B(24,20) , C(24,20)] for 1st cycle then again same one for 2nd cycle till last one in the end I have big dataframe which has 3*480 columns through cycles

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question fully but this is a solution:

Convert your data frame to a 2d numpy array using as_matrix() then use ravel() to get a vector of size 480 * 3 then cycle over your cycles and use vstack method for stacking rows over each other in your result, this is a code with your example data:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4], [10,20,30,40]]
B = [[4,5,6,7], [40,50,60,70]]
C = [[8,9,10,11], [80,90,100,110]]

cycles = 2

for cycle in range(cycles):
    data = {'A': A[cycle], 'B': B[cycle], 'C': C[cycle]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    D = df.as_matrix().ravel()
    if cycle == 0:
        Results = np.array(D)
    else:
        Results = np.vstack((Results, D2))
# Output: Results= array([[  1,   4,   8,   2,   5,   9,   3,   6,  10,   4,   7,  11], [ 10,  40,  80,  20,  50,  90,  30,  60, 100,  40,  70, 110]], dtype=int64)
np.savetxt("Results.csv", Results, delimiter=",")
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I was wondering if is it **reversible** I mean how can I regenerate my matrices A , B , C  through loops by `def mkdf()` `def print_df()` from **Results.csv** ?